# Segmentation fault:11, code works on windows but not mac

Tags: c

This function should print out a textual representation of the bytes in the file called `filename`. It worked on windows, but gives a segmentation fault: 11 on mac, thanks for any help

```
int hexdump(FILE *streaminput, FILE *streamoutput)
{   
unsigned char buffer[8];
int bytescount;
int n = 0;
streaminput=fopen(filename, "rb");//read binary file
setvbuf(streaminput,NULL,_IOFBF,1024);//Buffer size to 1024 bytes
if(streaminput==0)
{
    printf("cannot open file");
    return 0;
}
for (;;)//read to the end of file,end feof(stream)!=0//
{   
    bytescount=fread(buffer,1,8,streaminput);//fread(void *buffer, 
size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream)//
    //dec2hex(n, buf);//
    if (bytescount==0)
    {
        fprintf(streamoutput,"%07X",n);
        break;
    }
    fprintf(streamoutput,"%07X",n);

    for(int i=0;i<bytescount;i++)
    {
        if(((char)buffer[i] >= 32) && ((char)buffer[i] <= 126))
        {
            //fprintf(streamoutput,"  %02x%c ",buffer[i],buffer[i]);
            printf(" %02X %c ",buffer[i],buffer[i]);
            //printf("%c",isprint(buffer[i]),buffer[i]);//
        }   
        else
        {
        printf(" %02X . ",buffer[i],buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    n = n+bytescount;
    if (bytescount <8)
    {
        fprintf(streamoutput,"%07X",n);
        break;
    }


}
fclose(streaminput);
streaminput=NULL;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you don't check that the file was opened successfully until after you call `setvbuf()`, you likely are getting a failure to open the file and crashing in `setvbuf()` with a null file stream pointer.  At the lest, that's the first place to look.  Signal 11 is 'segmentation fault'; your code is accessing memory it shouldn't.

Comment: use a debugger.

Comment: This works fine assuming the file exists.  Make sure you check the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: **1.** What's the purpose of defining `streaminput` as an input parameter to the function, if you never use the value passed...? **2.** What exactly is the `filename`...?

Answer (score 0):

i guess your problem is with path the path you give in windows is like

```
C:\Users\Name\b.txt
```

but in linux and mac is something like

```
/home/name/b.txt
```

it's recommended to use relative path and use file separator

```
inline char separator()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    return '\\';
#else
    return '/';
#endif
}
```

Comment: how would i do this?

Comment: Or you could just use `/` as a directory separator on Windows.

Comment: use should use separator for giving file path